# where is my html page in visual studio?

Tags: html, image, src, display

I know I need to put my image in the html folder of my project in order to be able to display it .When I use  it doesn't display anything only the given alt tag of the picture. I was wondering if it will work if I put my P7220399.JPG image in the folder where my .sln project file is located, but it doesn't seem to work that way either! I am using visual studio.

```
    <header>
        <img src="P7220399.JPG" alt ="win" title ="products" style ="width: 304px;height:228px;"/>
    </header>
```

in the example above the .JPG is in the project directory where my .sln file is located.

what should I do to display the image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First:

Create a folder in your solution named "Images", and place all your images in this folder. From than, make your source-url like this: `/Images/P7220399.jpg`.

### How the rooting works in your solution:

Lets say this is your solution:

[image: Layout]

Let's say your page is in the `Views` folder, you will need to get one folder back to the main folder, and after that to the Content and than the Images folder. Your source-url will look like:

`../Content/Images/P7220399.jpg`

The `../` is for getting one folder back from the current folder you are.